# Differences in orthography between variants

Tags: ortografia, português-europeu, português-brasileiro, diferenças

Now that Brazil has revised its orthography to conform to Portuguese orthography in 2009, what are the prime differences in orthography between the various regional variants of written Portuguese? The only difference I have noticed are

1. the stressed open/closed O, as in *fenômeno* (BR) vs. *fenómeno* (PT), and
2. the open/closed E, as in *gênero* (BR) vs. *género* (PT).

Are there other differences in Portuguese orthography?

Comment: Good question but too broad?

Comment: @bigown Depends. Maybe there are no more differences...? (I'm not asking for a list of all such _words_, just for a list of rules.)

Comment: There's also *fato/facto*

Comment: Asking for all other differences is overkill, IMO. European Portuguese and Brazilian Portuguese can have a broad partition of their own vocabulary, in fact.

Comment: @E_net4 But I wouldn't count different vocabulary as a difference in _orthography_. I'm just asking about _spelling differences_ of the same word (and **not** about all the differences of the written language).

Comment: I understand that, but finding all cases is a tricky task and requires a very good answer.

Comment: A good answer doesn't have to be exhaustive. I could probably summarize the main [differences between America English and British English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_in_British_English) in a couple of points, both spelling and punctuation. I was expecting the differences between European Portuguese and Brazilian Portuguese to be less after the Novo Acordo Ortográfico.

Answer (score 3):

There are still differences, because the revised orthography respects differences in pronunciation between the regional variants.

The orthographic agreement can be summed up in a few categories, of which the last two listed here allow double orthography, or even distinct orthographies.

> 1. some types of words have now their first letter in lower case
>      Primavera - primavera
>      Norte - norte
> 2. suppression of voiceless consonants
>      acção - ação
>      excepto - exceto

When the consonant isn't totally mute, or both versions of the word can be heard, there is double orthography, that is, the agreement doesn't prescribe one way over the other:

> espectável + espetável
>   conceptual + concetual

When the word is pronounced differently, there are different ways of writing it:

> *adoção* (Portugal) and *adopção* (Brasil)
>   *intercetar* (Portugal) and *interceptar* (Brasil)

**Note:** Ironically, words that previously were written the same way in both variants, are now written differently in order the respect the phonetic criteria. This change raised a few issues against its acceptance.

> 3. suppression of certain accents
>      eles lêem - eles leem
>      heróico - heroico

Again, when there are differences in the pronunciation, both orthographies coexist, as was referred in the question:

> *sénior* (Portugal) and *sênior* (Brasil)
>   *sinfónico* (Portugal) + *sinfônico* (Brasil)

But also the conjugation of the first person plural in the past perfect tense of verbs belonging to the first class (ending in *-ar*):

> nós andámos, nós procurámos (Portugal)
>   (to distinguish from the present tense)
>
> nós andamos, nós procuramos (Brasil)

Comment: I'm finding conflicting information on the internet for *adoção* and *intercetar* in Brazil. Are you sure you wrote that part correctly?

Comment: @DanGetz I used those examples from a reference published with a portuguese newspaper a few years ago. As the orthographic agreement didn't find a consensus across all the portuguese speaking countries, it's pretty tricky to answer this question. Any suggestions for improvement are welcome.